# Is it possible to deselect a group while keeping the original selection selected?

Tags: groups, selection-tools

You can select a group of objects by selecting one object of that group and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *> Group*

Is it possible to deselect a group, while keeping the rest of the original selection selected?
(e.g. box select a lot of objects, then deselect all of them that are in a certain group.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
2. "Select" the group as you specify, with the *Extend* option enabled.
3. Reinvert the selection.

This works for many things, not just groups.

Answer (score 7):

Switch the filter type to "Group" in Outliner, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>LMB</kbd> on group icon(s) to (de)select.